# How do I add a click button outside the menu to open a new text field instead of clicking on "other"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, drop-down-menu

I can not figure out how to use a click button (it could be a plus sign) outside the drop down menu instead of clicking on "other" so the user can enter another value ? thanks!!

Here is the html:

```
<form onsubmit="FormSubmit(this);">
<label for="last_name">Brand:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="brand" />
<select name="fruit_ddl" onchange="DropDownChanged(this);">
<option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="brand1">Brand1</option>
<option value="brand2">Brand2 </option>
<option value="brand3">Brand3</option>
<option value="">Other..</option>

</select> <input type="text" name="brand_txt" style="display: none;" />
<button type="submit">Add Brand</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function DropDownChanged(oDDL) {
    var oTextbox = oDDL.form.elements["brand_txt"];
    if (oTextbox) {
        oTextbox.style.display = (oDDL.value == "") ? "" : "none";
        if (oDDL.value == "")
            oTextbox.focus();
    }
}

function FormSubmit(oForm) {
    var oHidden = oForm.elements["brand"];
    var oDDL = oForm.elements["brand_ddl"];
    var oTextbox = oForm.elements["brand_txt"];

    if (oHidden && oDDL && oTextbox)
        oHidden.value = (oDDL.value == "") ? oTextbox.value : oDDL.value;
}
```

Comment: You want to be able to dynamically add `<option>` elements to your dropdown?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. yes I want to switch that "other" in the drop down by adding a click button outside the menu that have the same function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv9kb/) does what you want?
I kept the "Other" option, and the plus button just selects that.
(I had to chage the "Other" value, because it was the same as the null value.)

I basically added a plus button with this onclick handler:

```
function PlusClick(btn) {
    var ddl = btn.form.elements["fruit_ddl"];
    ddl.value = "-";    
    DropDownChanged(ddl);
}
```

Edit: Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv9kb/1/), with the "Other" option removed.